# change custom annotation text without removing them iPhone

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview

I have a query which is almost similar to my previous question but Since I didnt got the answer there Here's the another scenario

I have 2 annotation on the map with label 1 and 2 now I want to replace their values.

Is it possible without removing both the annotation and inserting them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls go through the project from this link [Moving annotations](https://github.com/100grams/Moving-MKAnnotationView). It changes the coordinates without removing them. I think you can try something similar to that.

> But i think its also possible if you
>   have reference to that annotation.